# How can I release stuck modifier keys (alt, ctrl etc) in VMware Workstation?

Tags: keyboard, vmware-workstation

I have a VMware machine which has got trapped thinking that `Alt` is down - so trying to type results in activating menu functions like save etc. How can I return it to reality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the operating system is Windows, you can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to force keys to be released:

```
Send, {Shift Up}
Send, {LShift Up}
Send, {RShift Up}
Send, {Alt Up}
Send, {LAlt Up}
Send, {RAlt Up}
Send, {Control Up}
Send, {LControl Up}
Send, {RControl Up}
Send, {LWin Up}
Send, {RWin Up}
ExitApp
```

---

Documentation:

- [Send](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)

Answer (score 2):

- The [VMware Knowledge Base Entry on the topic](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1480) recommends to press the stuck keys individually, inside the VM. However, this doesn't always work (it didn't work for me today).
- You can also try holding the keys down as you grab the input into the virtual machine, then releasing them. This too doesn't always work.
- In the case of the above not working, you will have to convince the guest operating system to change them:

  - On Windows, go to the *Accessibility Options* (sometimes known as *Ease of Access Center*) in the *Control Panel*, and enable *StickyKeys*. This will turn `Ctrl`, `Alt` and `Shift` on and off with each keypress, rather than when held down. Press the stuck key until it is in the off state, then turn off *Sticky Keys* again. (Note: you can also turn *StickyKeys* on by pressing `Shift` five times in a row in the default setup)
  - On a Linux OS, [this advice](http://javier.rodriguez.org.mx/index.php/2009/01/15/uhowto-recover-stuck-modified-keys-from-vmware-player-or-workstation) may help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running Windows, this question is relevant whether you are running it as a guest OS in a VM or not.  The AHK script suggested by iglvzx is relevant in principle; but it may not help if the problem prevents you from being able to execute it.  I suggest the following script:

```
; The following command will normally cure a stuck modifier key.  The hotkey
; uses all 4 modifiers because this is the only combination that is guaranteed
; to work if any of them (without knowing which) is/are logically stuck.  
^+#!m::                               ; Control-Shift-Windows-Alt-M
  Send, {Shift Up}
  Send, {LShift Up}
  Send, {RShift Up}
  Send, {Alt Up}
  Send, {LAlt Up}
  Send, {RAlt Up}
  Send, {Control Up}
  Send, {LControl Up}
  Send, {RControl Up}
  Send, {LWin Up}
  Send, {RWin Up}
  MsgBox 0, Stuck Modifier,  Fix ran., 1
  Return
```

You can put the script in a .ahk file and put a shortcut to it in your Startup folder so that it will always be available in case of 'emergency'.  If you don't like seeing the AHK tray icon for it, add a line with #NoTrayIcon at the beginning.  If you don't like the brief confirmation that the script ran, you can delete that MsgBox line.

Answer (score 0):

I had more or less the same pb : my shift key would get stuck if i presses simultaneously alt+shift.

Found a [hotfix on the microsoft website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2847932) that solved my problem. The fix solves rdk modifier key synchronization.

Click on "Hotfix Download Available" to download.

Then run it on the client machine.